# Worksheet_Change cannot work on cells updated by formula

Tags: excel, vba, worksheet-function

I would like to call a macro if the values of the cells in column 30 change, and all the cells in column 30 has input like '=A1-C1' (formula format). In this case, the Worksheet_Change will not work, correct? But how can I possible fix it by using worksheet_calculate? Or any other functions?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

     If Target.Column = 30 Then
        ThisRow = Target.Row
        If Target.Value > 0.1 Then
            Range("AJ" & ThisRow).Select
            Call Mail_with_outlook
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe (not tested):

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim r As Range
    
Set r = Columns(30)
If Not Intersect(Target, r.Precedents) Is Nothing Then
    r.Cells(Target.Row).Select
End If
End Sub
```